# sass loader does not convert scss to css

Tags: javascript, node.js, sass, webpack

I have .scss file with variable declaration:

```
$zBackground: #0147A7;

.bodyclass {
  background: $zBackground;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

a {
  color: purple;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

After doing Webpack build the output is same , the variables are not parsed.
Though I am not getting any error on build.

```
$zBackground: #0147A7;

.bodyclass {
  background: $zBackground;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

a {
  color: purple;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

$font-stack:    Helvetica, sans-serif;
$primary-color: #333;

body {
  font: 100% $font-stack;
  color: $primary-color;
}
a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

current Webpack Config is below :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

var extractAppCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('appStyle.css', {
    allChunks: false
});
var extractBootStrapCss = new ExtractTextPlugin('vendorStyle.css', {
    allChunks: false
});

module.exports = {
    /*devtool: 'source-map',*/
    entry: {
        app: path.join(__dirname, '/web/app/client/app.js'),
        vendor: ['jquery', 'angular', 'angular-ui-router', 'oclazyloads', 'bootstrapJS']
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/web/app/dist/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: "",
        chunkFilename: '[name]-[id]-[hash]-[chunkhash].js'
/*
[named] is replaced by the name of the chunk set at require.ensure

[id] is replaced by the id of the chunk.

[hash] is replaced by the hash of the compilation.

[chunkhash] is replaced by the hash of the chunk.

*/
    },
    resolve: {
        modulesDirectories: ["node_modules", "bower_components"],
        alias: {
            jquery: __dirname + "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
            bootstrapJS: __dirname + "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
            bootstrapCSS: __dirname + "/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
            oclazyloads: __dirname + "/node_modules/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js",
        }
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            loaders: ['ng-annotate', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=stage-0']
        }, {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'html-loader'
        }, {
            test: /[\/\\]bootstrap[\/\\]*\.css$/,
            loader: /*"style!css"*/ extractBootStrapCss.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')

        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader:  extractAppCss.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap')
        }, {
            test: /\.(png)$/,
            loaders: ['file-loader?name=/img/png/[name].[ext]']
        }, {
            test: /\.(svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
            loaders: ['file-loader?name=/img/[name].[ext]']
        }, {
            test: /\.(jpg)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        // Injects bundles in your index.html instead of wiring all manually.
        // It also adds hash to all injected assets so we don't have problems
        // with cache purging during deployment.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'web/app/client/index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            filename: 'index.html'
        }),
        extractAppCss,
        extractBootStrapCss,
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
          new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'web/app/client/error.html'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/img/favicon.ico',
            to: './img/favicon.ico'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/hometemplate.html',
            to: 'hometemplate.html'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/module2',
            to: './module2'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/core',
            to: './core'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/foo',
            to: './foo'
        }, {
            from: 'web/app/client/bar',
            to: './bar'
        }]),
        //Manual vendor separation
        //new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js'),
        // Automatically move all modules defined outside of application directory to vendor bundle.
        // If you are using more complicated project structure, consider to specify common chunks manually.
        /*  new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
              name: 'vendor',
              minChunks: function(module, count) {
                console.log(module.resource);
                  return module.resource && module.resource.indexOf(path.resolve(__dirname, 'web')) === -1;
              }
          }),*/
          new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
           // The order of this array matters
           names: ["common", "vendor"],
           minChunks: 2
       }),
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
    ]
};
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue. Try changing the loader for the `scss` files from this:

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader:  extractAppCss.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap', 'sass-loader?sourceMap')
}
```

To this:

```js
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loader:  extractAppCss.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader?sourceMap!sass-loader?sourceMap')
}
```